# jquery- how to prevent next page from executing unless required fields are entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form look like below:

[image]

The process is simple, you have to fill up the details of the first tab and proceed to the next tab and finally to the last tab and sign up. All fields in each tab are required of course. I figured the best way to do a client side validation is to validate each tab everytime someone clicks the next button.

I tried implementing it using jquery validation via below:

```
  <div class="card-body">

                <!-- Dealer Registration Form -->
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" id="register-form">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                        <!-- Registration  Tab-->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="registration" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="registration-tab">
                            <h5 class="text-center" style="background-color: #303030; color: #ffffff; padding: .5rem; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">Account Particulars</h5>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required id="email" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required id="password">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="password-confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Next Button -->
                            <div class="text-right">
                                <!-- <a class="btn btn-secondary next-button" id="information-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#information" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Next</a> -->
                                <a class="btn btn-secondary next-button" id="next-btn">Next</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Information Tab -->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="information" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="information-tab">
                            <!-- Personal Particulars -->
                            <h5 class="text-center" style="background-color: #303030; color: #ffffff; padding: .5rem; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">Personal Particulars</h5>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="full_name">Full Name (as per NRIC)</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="nric">NRIC Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="nric" class="form-control" id="nric" placeholder="NRIC Number">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="address_1">Address Line 1</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="address_1" id="address_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Residential Address Line 1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="address_1">Address Line 2</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="address_2" id="address_2" class="form-control" placeholder="Residential Address Line 1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="address_1">Address Line 3</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="address_3" id="address_3" class="form-control" placeholder="Residential Address Line 1">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="city">City</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="state">State</label>
                                    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                                        <option disabled selected>Choose your state..</option>
                                        @foreach($states as $state)
                                        <option class="text-capitalize" value="{{ $state->id }}">{{ $state->name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="contact_number_home">Contact Number (Home)</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="contact_number_home" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Contact Number">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="contact_number_mobile">Contact Number (Mobile)</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="contact_number_mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Contact Number">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <label style="display: block;" for="existing_customer_options">Are you an existing Destiny Code customer?</label>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="existing_customer" value="0" checked>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="existing_customer">No</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="existing_customer" value="1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="existing_customer">Yes</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Next Button -->
                            <div class="text-right">
                                <!-- <a class="btn btn-secondary next-button" id="agreement-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#agreement" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Next</a> -->
                                <a class="btn btn-secondary next-button">Next</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="agreement" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="agreement-tab">
                            <h5 class="text-center" style="background-color: #303030; color: #ffffff; padding: .5rem; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">Agreement</h5>

                            <!-- Registration Agreement -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 mb-0">
                                    <div class="overflow-auto agreement">
```

.......and so on

Script:

```
 // Validate each input tab before moving to the next tab

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
              required: true,
              // Specify that email should be validated
             // by the built-in "email" rule
             email: true
                   },
                 password: {
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 10
                 },
            password_confirmation:"required"
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Please enter an email",
            password: "Please enter a password",
            password_confirmation: "Please confirm your password"
        }
    });

    $('#next-btn').on('click',function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#register-form").valid();
        });

    });
```

The problem is I can still proceed to the next tab even if nothing is being entered, though the error message asking for input does show. How do I make it work?

Edit:

```
 // Validate each input tab before moving to the next tab


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
        email: {
              required: true,
              // Specify that email should be validated
             // by the built-in "email" rule
             email: true
                   },
        password: {
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 8,

                 },
        password_confirmation:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            equalTo: "#password"

        }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Please enter an email",
            password: "Please enter a password",
            password_confirmation: "Password does not match"
        }
    });

    $('#next-btn').on('click',function(e) {


       if( $("#register-form").valid()) {


        currentTab.removeClass('active');
        nextTab.find('a').trigger('click');
        nextTab.addClass('active');
        currentTab = $('.nav-tabs > .active');
        nextTab = currentTab.next('li');
          }else{
        e.preventDefault();   



    }
});
});
```

Comment: Hope its helps you [Bootstarap snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/j6rkb)

Comment: how did you make it work??

Comment: Its a bootstrap wizard  you can check source code

Comment: I solved it but how do I make sure password and confirm pass is same?

Comment: Post your JS validation code here so, i can check it .

Comment: Ok I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button until the form is valid.

```
 $('input').on('blur', function() {
    if($("#register-form").valid()) {
        $("#next-btn").prop('disabled', false);  
    } else {        
        $("#next-btn").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Also set next button to be diabled initially

```
disabled="disabled" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sk8pz36/)

Comment: what does the$ sign means?

Comment: what does it do?